# Como armar una lista con todas aquellas palabras que terminen en -mente dentro de una string que se pase como input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, regex, arraylist

```py
import re

input_text = "No puedo asegurarte ni fácilmente ni rápidamente, si esta red ampliamente conocida se trata de un ente consiente o/y con mente, aunque opcionalmente puedo simplemente asegurarte que funciona rápidamente y consigue eficientemente estos llamativos resultados." # example 1

#Creo que este grupo de captura podría servir para identificarles (almenos uno a uno)
recog_pattern = r"((?:\w+))?" + "mente"

list_adverbs_of_manner, list_adverbs_of_manner_aux = [], []

#Se le incorporarían los elementos identificados a la lista  list_adverbs_of_manner
#AQUI LO QUE FALTA que es pasarle los datos a la lista  list_adverbs_of_manner


#Eliminará los duplicados usando la lista auxiliar
for adverb_of_manner in list_adverbs_of_manner:
    if adverb_of_manner not in list_adverbs_of_manner_aux:
        list_adverbs_of_manner_aux.append(item)
list_adverbs_of_manner = list_adverbs_of_manner_aux

#Eliminaria casos especiales
#list_adverbs_of_manner.remove("ampliamente")

print(list_adverbs_of_manner)
```

Este es el output que debería obtener tras extraer de la string que se pase como input, todos los adverbios de modo, y luego de ser eliminados los repetidos usando este código, debería darme:

```
["fácilmente", "rápidamente", "ampliamente", "opcionalmente", "simplemente", "eficientemente"]
```

Notar, que ni la palabra `"mente"` ni `"ente"` , fueron capturadas ya que la regex que se encarga de extraerlas debería tener en cuenta que para que sea un adverbio de modo no puede estar tan solo la substring `"mente"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución:

```
import re

list_adverbs_of_manner = ["ampliamente"]

input_text = "No puedo asegurarte ni fácilmente ni rápidamente, si esta red ampliamente conocida se trata de un ente consiente o/y con mente, aunque opcionalmente puedo simplemente asegurarte que funciona rápidamente y consigue eficientemente estos llamativos resultados." # example 1
patron = re.compile(r"(\w+mente)")

manners = set(x for x in patron.findall(input_text) if x not in list_adverbs_of_manner)
list_adverbs_of_manner = list(manners)
print(list_adverbs_of_manner)
```

produce:

```
['simplemente', 'eficientemente', 'fácilmente', 'opcionalmente', 'rápidamente']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El patrón `\w+mente` reconoce todas las palabras terminadas en "mente" y que tenga una o más letras por delante.

Con `findall()` extraemos una lista de palabras que calzan con el patrón.

Con eso hacemos una comprensión de listas descartando las palabras que se encuentren en `list_adverbs_of_manner`.

Las palabras encontradas son puestas en un `set`, para eliminar automáticamente las duplicadas.